# download image blobs from mysql to local machine using bash?

Tags: mysql, bash, jpeg

I have a bunch of jpeg images stored as blobs on a mysql database which I need to download to my local machine, the following does not work, can someone please advise?

Note I know the below code just overwrites the same file but for the purpose of this exercise it does not matter.

```
IFS=$'\n'

for i in `mysql -sN -u******* -p******** -h****** -e "select my_images from mutable"; do

    echo $i > myimage.jpg
done
```

Comment: This seems like it's going to break if any of the JPEGs contain bytes corresponding to ASCII whitespace.

Comment: any good fix for this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what what `mysql` returns, and don't have an installation to test, but do read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001. I think that may be all you need, along with quoting `$i` (that is, `"$i"` instead of `$i`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what is not working with your code, but you should be able to fetch all data and save each image like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=0;

for i in `mysql -s -N -u******* -p******** -h****** -e"select my_images from mutable"`; do
  echo $i > "image${counter}.jpg";
  counter=$((counter+1));
done
```

Comment: would i need to store the files as binary or would the above just work is the most important thing to me

Comment: I assume you are storing the data as binary in the database. If that's the case the above should be sufficient. And yes you need to store the files as binary on your filesystem.

Comment: my ubuntu instance is remove, is there a way to verify these images are valid? Ie view them

Comment: @godzilla - Just look at the picture? If the data is stored correctly in the database there should be no problem with the files on disk.

Comment: @godzilla - Well in that case I don't think the image is stored correctly in your database?

Comment: Same problem here with PNGs, redirecting to a file from a MySQL, column type mediumblob. You can compare the files are different with `hexdump -C file.png | head`. I get some \n even with `IFS=""` or unset. Of course also size and `sha1sum` are different.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=0;
for i in `mysql -N -u * -p* -e "SELECT id from multable"`; do
  mysql -N -u * -p* -e "SELECT my_images FROM multable WHERE id=$i INTO DUMPFILE 
  '/var/lib/mysql-files/tmp.jpg';"
  mv /var/lib/mysql-files/tmp.jpg "image${counter}.jpg"
  counter=$((counter+1));
done
```

This code can extract image from blob and the image will not be invalid.
The keypoint is to use INTO DUMPFILE and then the file can save to the folder indicated by @@secure_file_priv. 
You can see the @@secure_file_priv by using the following command

```
$ echo "SELECT @@secure_file_priv" | mysql -u * -p
```

And you can change @@secure_file_priv value by setting it in my.cnf.
There are many my.cnf in mysql and you can check the loading sequence by following command

```
$ mysqld --help --verbose | grep cnf -A2 -B2
```

But I still suggest to use /var/lib/mysql-files/ to load image file from database first and then copy it because some version of MySQL can only use /var/lib/mysql-files folder even you have changed the @@priv_secure_file to indicate another folder.